DevExpress DataFormView - How to bind an object to a DataObject using MVVM?
I have a view with a XAML file:
<dxdf:DataFormView x:Name="LoginForm" DataObject="{Binding AuthenticateRequestObject}">
    <dxdf:DataFormTextItem FieldName="Username" />
    <dxdf:DataFormPasswordItem FieldName="Password" />
</dxdf:DataFormView>

<dxco:SimpleButton Text="Submit" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />

It's related C# logic:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(ILoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = loginViewModel;
    }
}

A model class:
public partial class AuthenticateRequest : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string username;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string password;
}

A ViewModel:
public interface ILoginViewModel
{

}

public partial class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel, ILoginViewModel
{
    public readonly ILoginService _loginService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public AuthenticateRequest authenticateRequestObject = new AuthenticateRequest();

    public LoginViewModel(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void Login()
    {
        var modelData = AuthenticateRequestObject;
    }
}

The objective is to bind AuthenticateRequestObject from the XAML file to authenticateRequestObject in LoginViewModel. The problem is it does not bind in the above code.
I would like to bind the DataObject AuthenticateRequestObject from the XAML to authenticateRequestObject in LoginViewModel.
